# I can't connect pyqt5 with mysql-connector

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ubuntu, pyqt5

when I activate conda on my bash shows me an error about mysql-connector module and when i deactivate the conda bash shows me an error by pyqt5 module and both are installed

I had reinstalled my linux and reinstall everything and it doesn't work. and reinstalled all modules and review my code

Without conda bash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 6, in <module>
    from SignIn_ui import IniciarSesionView
  File "../view/SignIn_ui.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

With conda bash:

```
File "controller.py", line 5, in <module>
    from model import RegisteredUser
  File "../model/model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from db_connection import DBconn
  File "../connection/db_connection.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Comment: How did you install them? always use `pip install`

Comment: yes i used it!.

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: My phython version is 3.7